# After every <p> tag insert a div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want after every `<p>` Tag to insert a div, defined with an id of course.

With *jQuery* is pretty easy with the [insertAfter](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/) like that:

```
$('#id').insertAfter('p'); but how about using css?
```

I can't see css *after* selector can help with that.

Comment: Are you asking if you can add content to your HTML with just CSS?

Comment: css cannot insert or create elements on its own. but you could **fake it** using psudo classes. `p:after { display: block; }` may work

Comment: `:after` + `content:` does not allow you to append elements; it's only used for text.

Comment: This seems like a poor idea - is there only one <p> tag in your page? this seems like it will duplicate #id?

Comment: CSS cannot alter HTML, only style it. Use jQuery, style <p>, or use server side code.

Comment: @JasonSperske answering like that makes me think my question is without point! Thank you

Comment: There is a valid use of CSS in this way, but it has a downside that will get in the way of your effort (see my answer)

Comment: @Jason: no, it can't. It can insert content, it can (in some browsers) change/update the `src` of an `img`. It *cannot* insert new elements (a pseudo-element, as the name implies, *is not* an element, and does not form a part of the DOM).

Comment: @DavidThomas, I understand your point, I hadn't drawn a distinction between content and elements.  I'll update my answer to be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert content (but as David Thomas points out it cannot alter the DOM structure by appending elements). Unfortunately for what you are asking, this content is escaped automatically and this approach is really intended to solve/create a different problem.

Take this HTML+CSS:

```
<p>A P element</p>
<style>
p:after
{
  content:"<div>A DIV element</div>";
}
</style>
```

Produces this:

```
A P element<div>A DIV element</div>
```

([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sperske/Mzder/))

Answer (score 6):

There are certainly :after selectors in the CSS3 standard. But CSS is used for styling. Inserting DOM elements are done via scripting.